# install python X.Y.Z 32 bits and 64 bits

Tags: python, windows, chocolatey

I am interested in installing python 32bits and 64bits with debugging symbols via chocolatey.

So far, if I do the following I can manage to install what I want, for the sake of an example let's have version 3.7.0.

```
choco install python3 --forcex86 --allowmultiple --version=3.7.0  --installargs "TargetDir=C:\Python37_32bits CompileAll=1 Include_debug=1 Include_symbols=1"
choco install python3 --force    --allowmultiple --version=3.7.0  --installargs "TargetDir=C:\Python37        CompileAll=1 Include_debug=1 Include_symbols=1"
```

I need `--forcex86` to tell choco toinstall python-32bits version.
Later on I need `--force` to tell chocolatey, please don't complain you already installed python3.7.0.

**The problem:**:

Afterwards chocolatey seems not to know he has installed two versions of the same package.

Is there any clean way to achieve installing pythonXYZ 32bits and 64bits and manage them via chocolatey?

Comment: Why do you need 32 bits and 64 bits version of Python?

Comment: I need to load some 32bits & 64bits compiled dlls via cffi.